# Is it possible to restrict allowed filenames on a NFS share?

Tags: linux, nfs, filtering

In our mixed network the OSX clients like to create resource fork junk on our Linux NFS shares. What I'd like is a server setting much like Sambas *veto files*-directive to disallow creation of ._* folders.

I can't find anything like it in NFS man-pages (*export, nfs, nfsd, exportfs*), maybe it could be configured on the underlying filesystem?

ps.
I am aware of *defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true* to make OSX not create *.DS_Store*-files on network disks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you should be able to remove these directories very soon as they are created using inotify feature. I would check out [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en) or [fsniper](http://projects.l3ib.org/trac/fsniper), they look very promising.

Comment: These tools indeed look like they could do the work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally preventing the creation of files/directories matching a certain path is a tiny part of an elephant called mandatory access control (MAC). It is a main part of SELinux. MAC integrated into NFS [is not here yet](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Labeled_NFS), but for your needs it is indeed sufficient to act on filesystem level.

But it's most certainly too cumbersome solution for your problem :)

Comment: That indeed looks like a mighty big canon to solve this tiny nuisance. But thank you for the information, I will definitely read up on it. I've previously only experienced head aches with trying to get NFS to work smoothly with SELinux turned on.